# Как сделать подход TPT через Fluent API при наследовании от обобщенного класса?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Опишу суть. Есть несколько типов услуг (`Service.cs`, `ServiceMeetGuest.cs`) и тип заявок (`Bid.cs`, `BidMeetGuest.cs`). С миграциями в типах услуг все просто.

А вот типы заявок наследуются от обобщенного класса, в обобщенный тип `TService` указывается вид услуги. Пробовал сделать таким образом, есть обобщенный класс:

```
public class BidBase<TService>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [ForeignKey("Service")]
    [Required]
    public long ServiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual TService Service { get; set; }
}
```

И обьявление сущности в `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
public DbSet<BidBase<Service>> Bids { get; set; }
public DbSet<BidBase<ServiceMeetGuest>> BidsMeetGuest { get; set; }
```

Как оказалось, Entity Framework не поддерживает обобщенные типы. Поэтому решил добавить классы:

```
public class Bid : BidBase<Service> { }
public class BidMeetGuest : BidBase<ServiceMeetGuest> {}
```

И `DbSet`ы:

```
public DbSet<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
public DbSet<BidMeetGuest> BidsMeetGuest { get; set; }
```

Все ок, но связи между ними нету никакой, Entity Framework воспринимает их как 2 разные сущности, хотя они наследуемы от `BaseBid.cs`. Как сделать между ними подход Table Per Type (https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/7.2.php) через Fluent Api?

Comment: Что-то не понял ничего, а зачем вам в модели сервис?

Comment: @sp7 это "услуга" - сущность в предметной области. А не класс-сервис в терминах архитектуры:)

Comment: @PashaPash трудности перевода )

Answer (score 0):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bid>().ToTable("BidBase");
modelBuilder.Entity<BidMeetGuest>().ToTable("BidBase");
```